# How do I boot from my Mac partition?

Tags: mac, windows, bootcamp, disk-format

I tried to install Windows 7 on my Mac via Boot Camp, but the disk of Windows 7 doesn't work. When I tried to install the Windows 7 it shows a black screen.

Now I want to boot back to OS X, but I don't know how.

Do I have to re-insert the Mac disk? If yes, how can I take out the disk from the Mac?

Answer (score 6):

Hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key when you power on and you can choose the working mac partition or insert a bootable DVD to get back to disk utility or a working os. This is called the [Startup Manager](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1310) screen.

The eject key will work once the Startup Manager is running so you can eject the windows DVD.

As I didn't explain the option key - here is a [great article explaining how Mac users refer to the keys on the keyboard as well as some handy shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) for later once things work again.

Comment: I'll try thanks you! hmm, what is "Option" key?

Comment: @Daniel The "option" key says "option" on Apple keyboards and "Alt" on other keyboards.

Comment: It says 'Alt' on most modern Apple keyboards in fact, at least here in the UK/Ireland (and at least on laptop keyboards).